# Kernel Panic Help - 2013 Mac Pro (Trashcan)

Tags: macos, mac-pro, kernel

Been getting this k-panic once a day for the past year or so... No rhyme or reason to it, but it happens at least once a day. System slows down just a little bit, not to an unusable point, however...

It was happening twice a day, until I plugged in my Magic Trackpad 2 with lightning cable to the Mac Pro. Plugging in wireless numeric keyboard didn't make a difference. Thought I was onto something when I figured out the trackpad thing.

After reading a few other form pages about kernel panics that are frequent, I reinstalled macOS Mojave a few times. Reinstalling seems to resolve the issue and then after about a week and a half of use after reinstall, its back to its old ways.

I've been told by an "expert" that this is a likely sign of a failing processor. If so, fine... Ive been wanting to upgrade from 4 cores to 8 or 12 for a while. Buying it with 4 was a huge mistake. But I would like to get a second opinion from MacExchange here and see if its something else entirely.

My system after reboot says your computer rebooted because of a problem, press any key to reboot... Even though I initiated the reboot in the first place, it seems to think it crashed and rebooted itself.

I hit space, the Mac chime plays, and I am back in business. Once I login, a window pops up and says your Mac experienced an error, this will be automatically sent to apple for further review.

Then on the next window behind it, a window with this kernel panic text shows, and offers a box for a comment.

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f90c094cf): nvme: "Fatal error occurred. CSTS=0xffffffff US[1]=0x0 US[0]=0x5 VID=0x126f DID=0x2260
. FW Revision=C2.3.23A\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IONVMeFamily/IONVMeFamily-470.0.9/IONVMeController.cpp:5258
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa40768bab0 : 0xffffff800ef42afb 
0xffffffa40768bb00 : 0xffffff800f079ca5 
0xffffffa40768bb40 : 0xffffff800f06b70e 
0xffffffa40768bb90 : 0xffffff800eee9bb0 
0xffffffa40768bbb0 : 0xffffff800ef421e7 
0xffffffa40768bcb0 : 0xffffff800ef425cb 
0xffffffa40768bd00 : 0xffffff800f6d3419 
0xffffffa40768bd70 : 0xffffff7f90c094cf 
0xffffffa40768bd90 : 0xffffff7f90bf448a 
0xffffffa40768bef0 : 0xffffff7f90bf466c 
0xffffffa40768bf30 : 0xffffff800f6a910b 
0xffffffa40768bf70 : 0xffffff800f6a8e28 
0xffffffa40768bfa0 : 0xffffff800eee913e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily(2.1)[64F47940-9067-34AA-8BE0-00A3D318D744]@0xffffff7f90be6000->0xffffff7f90c28fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[A0EA3BA4-766A-31D0-A942-6C22941D96A8]@0xffffff7f8f983000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[E55C8096-DBD1-3D37-B27E-956FC4EFC776]@0xffffff7f8faf1000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM(2.1)[5A0A0D72-00CA-3C23-BE21-CF3B76689409]@0xffffff7f8fcd9000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[40EAD563-6BDF-3A66-B9F7-D888DFE5BD0A]@0xffffff7f8f865000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[8A456F86-9DC7-3659-9690-DF50846852BA]@0xffffff7f8fa23000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19A546d

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Sun Aug 18 23:37:31 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.0.166~17/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 3DF78B9A-F155-3176-889D-DB780ED589D6
Kernel slide:     0x000000000ec00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800ee00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800ed00000
System model name: MacPro6,1 (Mac-F60DEB81FF30ACF6)
System shutdown begun: YES
Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002cd)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 160769377250874
last loaded kext at 78138008967322: >!AXsanScheme   3 (addr 0xffffff7f92143000, size 32768)
last unloaded kext at 66252159977307: >!UMergeNub   900.4.2 (addr 0xffffff7f91419000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
@filesystems.smbfs  3.4
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AMCCSControl  1.12
@kext.AMDFramebuffer    3.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000    3.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.0
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.1.46
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.1.46
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.0d105
>pmtelemetry    1
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.1.18
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!AHDA  283.13
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.2
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!A!IMCEReporter    113
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@kext.AMD7000!C 3.0.0
>!AMGPUPowerControl 4.1.46
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    153
>!UTopCaseDriver    153
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.8
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.0.28
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
>!A!ICPUPowerManagementClient   222.0.0
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    302
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
>!A!ICPUPowerManagement 222.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs  1.0
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.1.19
@kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices  3.0.0
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    800.14
>DspFuncLib 283.13
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  4.1.46
>!AHDA!C    283.13
|IOHDA!F    283.13
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.1.46
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  558.1
|IOGraphics!F   558.1
>!AGraphicsControl  4.1.46
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.0d105
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.0d105
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.0d105
>!AHS!BDriver   153
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.0d105
|IO!B!F 7.0.0d105
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.0d105
>!AActuatorDriver   3400.33
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>!AMultitouchDriver 3400.33
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3400.26
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.0
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.5.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.5
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>usb.!UEHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UEHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.0.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   800.14
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.0.2
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

My Mac Pro's Specs:
10.15 Catilina Beta (this didn't help, even a fresh install of it)
Mac Pro (Late 2013)
3.7GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon E5
32GB 1866 MHz DDR3
1TB SSD

Only thing on this Mac that isn't stock from Apple is the SSD. I upgraded this myself when I first got the machine. OWC MacSales had a promotion if you sent the one that came with your Mac in, you got an upgrade for $200. So I went from 512 to 1TB for $200. Never had issues with either drive.

Comment: I tried to re-format your panic report, but it looks like there's been some prior attempt. Could you replace with a clean version, then select all of it & hit Ctrl/K [not cmd, ctrl] which will format it as 'code'.

Comment: (1) Run hardware test (2) run in safe mode. Try a safe boot.
    Shutdown your machine.  Hold down the shift key.  Poweron.  The boot up will take longer than normal because the filesystem on the startup drive is being checked and repaired as needed.   All about safe mode including what features and apps safe boot leaves out.  Safe boot uses a software driver instead of using your machines video hardware.
      http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1455  (3) is there any way of turning off processors?

Comment: Hard test see: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257

Comment: This seems to have failed doing i/o. Have you disconnected all external devices?  Disconnected all network connections?

Answer (score 2):

> panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f90c094cf): nvme: "Fatal error occurred.

Your computer is failing to communicate properly with its [NVMe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NVM_Express) flash storage. This may be a problem with the built-in flash storage or with the processor, but either way it's almost certainly unrelated to the trackpad.

Given that you have installed an aftermarket SSD, my suspicion would be that it is failing. Unfortunately, since you no longer have the original drive, testing this theory may be difficult. :(

Comment: I’ll buy another and see if that does the trick! They are much cheaper today then they were in 2013!

Comment: Just experienced the same 'panic' and found this page. I've bought a second hand macbook with 3d party SSD installed (I've discovered it later). SSD model is Kingspec NE - 1TB. Don't repeat my mistake, guys. Check everything or buy new one from Apple!